# QP formulation of the LCP — KKT conditions

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am reading a [book](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9780898719000) on the [linear complementarity problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complementarity_problem) (LCP) that claims that the necessary KKT conditions for the problem

\begin{align}
\text{minimize} \quad &z^T(q + Mz) \\
\text{subject to} \quad &q + Mz \geq 0 \\
& \quad z \geq 0
\end{align}

are given by

\begin{align}
q + (M+M^T)z^* - M^Tu^* &\geq 0 \\
(z^*)^T(q + (M + M^T)z^* - M^Tu^* &= 0 \\
u^* &\geq 0 \\
(u^*)^T(q+Mz^*)&=0
\end{align}

where $z^*$ is an optimal solution and $u^*$ is a suitable vector of multipliers.

Can someone please explain how these are derived?

My understanding is that the necessary KKT conditions for the problem

\begin{align}
\text{minimize} \quad &f(x) \\
\text{subject to} \quad &g_i(x) \leq 0 \quad \text{for } i \in \{1, \dots, m\}\\
& h_i(x) = 0 \quad \text{for } i \in \{1, \dots, l\}
\end{align}

are given by

\begin{align}
\nabla f(\bar{x}) + \sum_{i=1}^{m} u_i \nabla g_i(\bar{x}) + \sum_{i=1}^{l} v_i \nabla h_i(\bar{x}) = 0 \\
u_i g_i(\bar{x}) = 0 \quad \text{for } i \in \{1, \dots, m\} \\
u_i \geq 0 \quad \text{for } i \in \{1, \dots, m\}
\end{align}

where $\bar{x}$ is an optimal solution, and $u_i$ and $v_i$ are unique scalars.

Comment: In the line $(z^*)^T(q + (M + M^T)z^* - M^Tu^* = 0$, where does the bracket close?

Comment: Sorry, that line should be $(z^*)^T(q + (M+M^T)z^* - M^Tu^*) = 0$ @Sudix